Starting a grid from the bottom left
I would like to create a grid that is similar to a chess layout and labeled from 1 to 100 starting at the bottom left. It should look somewhat like this:
...
5(white) 6(black) 7(white) 8(black)
1(black) 2(white) 3(black) 4(white)
I cannot get the labeling or coloring to display correctly. This is my attempt. How can I adjust it?
import SwiftUI

struct LevelOverviewView: View {
    
    let numberOfLevels = 100
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            LazyVGrid(columns: Array(repeating: GridItem(.fixed(70)), count: 4), content: {
                ForEach((1...numberOfLevels).reversed(), id: \.self) { i in
                    ZStack{
                        Rectangle()
                            .fill(i % 2 == 0 ? .black : .white)
                            .aspectRatio(1.0, contentMode: .fit)
                        Text("\(i)")
                            .foregroundStyle(i % 2 == 1 ? .black : .white)
                    }
                }
            })
        }
        .background(.red)
    }
}

#Preview {
    LevelOverviewView()
}




You could try this approach reversing the numbers in steps of 4, as shown in the
example code:
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        LevelOverviewView()
    }
}

struct GridCell: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    var value: Int
}


struct LevelOverviewView: View {
    @State private var gridCell: [GridCell] = []
    let numberOfLevels = 100
    let step = 4 // <--- here, adjust as desired
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            LazyVGrid(columns: Array(repeating: GridItem(.fixed(70)), count: step)) {
                ForEach(gridCell) { cell in
                    ZStack {
                        Rectangle()
                            .fill(cell.value % 2 == 0 ? .black : .white)
                            .aspectRatio(1.0, contentMode: .fit)
                        Text("\(cell.value)")
                            .foregroundStyle(cell.value % 2 == 1 ? .black : .white)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        .background(.red)
        .onAppear {
            gridCell = (1...numberOfLevels).map{ GridCell(value: $0) }.reversed()
            
            // --- here
            for i in stride(from: 0, to: gridCell.count, by: step) {
                let endIndex = min(i + step, gridCell.count)
                gridCell[i..<endIndex].reverse()
            }
        }
    }
}

